# Is it possible to create MapQuickItems from qml in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I'm working on a `PyQt5` and `Qml` application. The application displays 2 `QLineEdits`, 2 `QPushButton` and a map that is given from my `Qml`. One of the functionalities of the application is parsing(in `python`) through an `XML-List` with titles and coordinates and adding pins on the coordinates on the map. My problem is now that it only displays the last coordinate. I realized that it's because I only change the property of the pin Item in Qml and not create a new one. My Question is now: Is it possible to create `MapQuickItems` in python?

Comment: I know the question is a bit wierd, but I am new to `Qml` and I don't really know how to explain my problem better.

Comment: My question is, why you would want to do this, when you could probably create them in QML from a model that you have defined in Python and exposed to QML.

Comment: It's because I want to add multiple pins on the map and for that I need to create new pins and not just change the property of one model.(Is that what you meant?)

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean. You use a model, that holds properties for an arbitrary amount of pins. From that model you instantiate the pins in QML. I don't know the Map API and don't have it installed here, but I am pretty sure your `MapQuickItem` inherits either `QQuickItem` or at least `QObject` which means you can use them as a delegate in a `Repeater` or `Instantiator` to instantiate one of them for each entry in your model.

Comment: So basically, you change properties/add entries to a model, and the pins will be created by QML automatically.

Comment: Do you have like a small example how the model would look like in python? Because I understand what you mean but I don't know how to start it and on the internet I can't find helpful examples.

Comment: Read: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html - In your code, what is the `ListModel` in those examples will be ideally some descendend of a `QAbstractItemModel` you create in Python and expose it as a context property. I don't do python, but in C++ you would inherit from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html - I don't have pyqt docs at hand, and no example for that.

Comment: see next example: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/b2f190dbf191b2c345b35ae75f9dd354

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented [@derM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429800/is-it-possible-to-create-mapquickitems-from-qml-in-python#comment79816905_46429800) you only have to create a model and expose it to your QML, there is no documentation for PyQt, but we can take as reference to the C ++ documentation since the concepts are similar. As a sample of this I have created in the following model that contains the information of a marker, in this case consider the position and color of the marker.

```
class MarkerItem(object):
    def __init__(self, position, color=QColor("red")):
        self._position = position
        self._color = color

    def position(self):
        return self._position

    def setPosition(self, value):
        self._position = value

    def color(self):
        return self._color

    def setColor(self, value):
        self._color = value


class MarkerModel(QAbstractListModel):
    PositionRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
    ColorRole = Qt.UserRole + 2

    _roles = {PositionRole: QByteArray(b"markerPosition"), ColorRole: QByteArray(b"markerColor")}

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._markers = []

    def rowCount(self, index=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._markers)

    def roleNames(self):
        return self._roles

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.row() >= self.rowCount():
            return QVariant()
        marker = self._markers[index.row()]

        if role == MarkerModel.PositionRole:
            return marker.position()

        elif role == MarkerModel.ColorRole:
            return marker.color()

        return QVariant()

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():
            marker = self._markers[index.row()]
            if role == MarkerModel.PositionRole:
                marker.setPosition(value)

            if role == MarkerModel.ColorRole:
                marker.setColor(value)

            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return QAbstractListModel.setData(self, index, value, role)

    def addMarker(self, marker):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self._markers.append(marker)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return QAbstractListModel.flags(index)|Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def moveRandom(self, ix):
        ind = self.index(ix, 0)
        current_pos = self.data(ind, MarkerModel.PositionRole)
        next_pos = current_pos + 0.002*QPointF(random() - 0.5, random() - 0.5)
        self.setData(ind, next_pos, MarkerModel.PositionRole)
        self.setData(ind, QColor(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)), MarkerModel.ColorRole)
```

And then used in the following example:

**main.py**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    model = MarkerModel()
    model.addMarker(MarkerItem(QPointF(-12.0464, -77.0428), QColor("black")))
    model.addMarker(MarkerItem(QPointF(-12.0340, -77.0428), QColor("red")))

    model.addMarker(MarkerItem(QPointF(-12.0440, -77.0280), QColor("#9f5522")))

    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty('markerModel', model)

    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile("main.qml"))

    if len(engine.rootObjects()) == 0:
        sys.exit(-1)

    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)

    timer = QTimer(engine)
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: model.moveRandom(0))
    timer.start(100)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.5
import QtPositioning 5.5

Window {
    visible: true
    title: "Python OSM"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property int marker_size: 16

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin {
            name: "osm"
        }
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(-12.0464, -77.0428)
        zoomLevel: 14

        MapItemView {
            model: markerModel
            delegate: MapQuickItem{
                anchorPoint: Qt.point(2.5, 2.5)
                coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(markerPosition.x, markerPosition.y)
                zoomLevel: 0
                sourceItem: Rectangle{
                    width:  marker_size
                    height: marker_size
                    radius: marker_size/2
                    border.color: "white"
                    color: markerColor
                    border.width: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obtaining what is shown in the following image:

[image]

*Note:* I added the moveRandom method to show you how to update the position of the markers, as you will see when executing the example a marker randomly moves

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/3f60a08691b4e8f57e3ef8badf567c6c)

Comment: Thank you very much!! This helped me a lot.